# Проверка ввода данных с формы

Tags: php

Такой вариант имеет право на существование?

```
$email = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($_POST['email'])));
```

Или глупый код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глупый.
Вот не глупый:

```
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email'])) : null;
```

При выводе данных пиши:

```
htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
```

Расписать почему так нужно не могу, я на пары спешу :)))

Comment: Спасибо КЭП. Для чего так нужно сам вижу.